# Rabbitmq Seamless upgrade without downtime

Tags: rabbitmq

I am planning to upgrade 3 node rabbitmq cluster. But I need to perform the upgrade without a downtime also I don't want to miss any messages in the queue. Can you please give me suggestions on how this can be achieved.

Version to be upgraded: 3.6.3 --> 3.7.5

Regards,

Rahul N.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [rabbitmq-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/rabbitmq-users/boIgGVbAKe0/a0BsUOzwAwAJ;context-place=forum/rabbitmq-users) group, we need to federate queues in the Vhosts individually.

We need to federate the vhosts and then shift the traffic for consumers to new green cluster. Once consumers start consuming the messages from green cluster, we can shift the producers to green cluster.